# Pandas - group sales by month

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with group sales for employee_ID by month.

with this:

```
date      |employee_ID |price
2000-01-01|    12      | 300
2000-01-02|    12      | 250
```

i want make this

```
date    | employee_ID |total_sales
2000-01 |     12            2
```

I dont know how to do this with groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='date'), 'employee_ID']).size().reset_index(name='total_sales')
```

Or month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.to_period('m'), 'employee_ID']).size().reset_index(name='total_sales')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `groupby` in this case is to use `value_counts`:

1. If the `dtype` of column `date` is `str`:

```
>>> df.value_counts([df['date'].str[:7], 'employee_ID']) \
      .reset_index(name='total_sales')

      date  employee_ID  total_sales
0  2000-01           12            2
```

2. If the `dtype` of column `date` is `datetime`:

```
>>> df.value_counts([df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), 'employee_ID']) \
      .reset_index(name='total_sales')

      date  employee_ID  total_sales
0  2000-01           12            2
```

You can replace: `df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')` by: `df['date'].dt.to_period('m')` as used by @jezrael.